# High impedance voltage source measurement with ADC

Tags: voltage, adc, high-impedance

I would like to measure voltage coming from a photodiode in open-circuit condition. The measurement is OK with classical digital voltmeter, but with an ADC internal (SAR) or external (Delta-Sigma) on Arduino, the value is not good.

I think it is due to the high impedance of source, I try with a follower OP without success.

Is it due to the mysterious leakage current of ADC input and have you an idea to solve this?

---

I add the schematic. It is a classical follower used for impedance matching.

[image: Photodiode_with _follower]

Comment: Welcome Marcel. Measuring the photodiode directly without a buffer is indeed not very promising. What did you try as a buffer ? Some opamps can have rather large input bias currents and could interfere substantially with the small photocurrent, which is to say that you essentially *must* use a FET input opamp. And you must set the DC working point of the photodiode correctly to be within the valid input voltage range. If ultimately you are interested in the light intensity of the diode, a transimpedance amplifier configuration is more usual (current-to-voltage converter).

Comment: Thank you for your response
I use an bipolar single supply OP, I don't know is an TLO81 can work in single supply alimentation.
We don't measure quantitatve value of light, but only variation (maximum).
The photodiode used here is a LED and the voltage open circuit in solar light is equal to 2.5 V, but with low light this voltage decrease to 30 mV.

Comment: The TL081 is a FET input opamp, so it could be used. It doesn't matter if you use single or dual supplies: From the point of view of the amplifier it only sees a negative and a positive supply and doesn't know where system ground is. As long as the input voltage is within the valid input voltage range, everything is good. Note that the TL081 input voltage range does *not* include the negative supply (which is ground in a single supply configuration).

Comment: Marcel, Your circuit description in words is far inferior to a circuit diagram. A TL081 buffer should allow photodiode voltage to be measured. But be aware that most multimeters load down a photodiode with \$10^7\$ ohms. A TL081 buffer will load far less, and give a different result. More commonly, a photodiode's *current* is measured, instead of voltage. Can you show us a circuit diagram of your buffer circuit, and how DC supplies are connected? It would also help to show DC supplie(s) to your analog-to-digital converter.

Comment: Put a resistor from the diode to ground and measure the voltage across the resistor. This will let you adjust the gain by simply changing the resistor size while preventing the ADC impedance from changing the reading.

Comment: @user1850479Thank you for this solution, but the purpose of the measure is to obtain the value of Voc (i.e current delivered by the photodiode is equal to 0)

Comment: @MarcelPasquinelli - Hi, I can see you are having some trouble adapting to the unique parts of Stack Exchange. I notice that you added an update to your already-deleted "non-answer". Other users could not see that, so I moved your schematic into its correct place, as an update (edit) of the question. || I will try to make things simple: Please immediately *stop* any further use of *answers* (either adding new ones or editing old ones). Instead, any improvements / new information etc. should be made as an [Edit] to the *question*. Thanks.

Comment: Replace the photodiode with a potentiometer (pot). Set the pot to the lowest and highest voltage(s) you expect to read and verify that with the DMM on the pot and ADC value after conversion from the source follower are proper readings. If the readings are not as intended then the problem is in your circuit wiring and/or program code.  If you get expected readings from the pot and then the photodiode then the next design step would be to translate the sensor output to the fit the whole ADC range to increase the resolution of your measurements. But you are not there yet.

Comment: @SystemTheory_thanks, I have alredy try the comparison beetwen classical DC source or battery with potentiometer and the values mesured by DMM and ADC are identical even for low voltage ( 50mV for instance).